# How to delete entire entry in firebase realtime database where some condition is true, through clearData() and user_privacy.json path?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Is it possible to write more advanced paths, dependent on a certain condition, in the user_privacy.json file to delete user data through the clearData() cloud function?

More specifically, we have a rather complex database structure implemented in firebase realtime database, and we are trying to implement a way for the user to automatically initiate account deletion from our app clients, which will also clear the database of any user generated data.

For example, we have feed entries which are stored in path:

/feedEntries/feedEntryId

and we would like to delete the entire feed entry where the user id equals the content of the following path:

/feedEntries/feedEntryId/profileKey

We assume that if we just write the path as stated in the docs for the clearData function, it will only remove the contents of the profileKey entry of the feed entry in question:

"database": {
"clearData": [
"/users/UID_VARIABLE",
"/feedEntries/feedEntryId(?)/profileKey/UID_VARIABLE"
]

What should be in place of the feedEntryId, to represent a dynamic feed entry id, making it check all feed entries for the profileKey in question?
Is it possible to make it delete the whole feed entry based on a comparison of the UID_VARIABLE and the contents of the "profileKey" entry?

If this is not possible, might we be able to achieve something similar, using db rules maybe?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1 . Proposition edit your rules to check if the user is allowed to delete : check if user token is the same user connected

```js
match /anonymous/{anonymousId} {
    allow delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == anonymousId;
}
```

2 . Proposition edit your rules  to check if the user is allowed to delete: you can also match the uid with another document's data or property

```js
match /items/{itemId} {
    allow delete: if (get(/databases/$(database)/documents/userAdmin/$(request.auth.uid)).data.itemId == itemId
}
```

3. Proposition use Cloud function transaction or  batched writes, run forEach on collection and remove document one by one inside a single transaction, please find below link on documentation

[Cloud function transaction,  batched writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions)

Comment: So I should simply set up user_privacy.json to clear data in path "/feedEntries", and then ensure through a database rule, that only feed entries which has a value in "profileKey" that matches the UID_VARIABLE can be overwritten. Only problem now is, that the code you have provided is the cloud firestore db rules syntax, while I am looking for realtime database rules syntax. With realtime database you cannot define rules to allow/disallow delete operations, you can only define rules for write/read/validate, and therefore, I am not certain this approach is even possible?

Comment: Could it be achieved by overwriting the value of a feed entrys "profileKey" with null, and then using !dataExists rule on /feedEntries/$feedEntryId level? Any input on how such a rule could be composed?

Comment: Please create a new answer, as I will have to downvote this one, on account of the mismatching platform tag.

Answer (score 0):

ok, you right ! no remove (aggregation) rule with real-time database only .write

however I'm sure you can solve your problem with transaction, the principe is to read what you want before update.

so you can read and check  profileKey === feedEntryId,  then you remove your item with update null or remove method

[doc firebase realtime-database: transaction with real-time database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions)

[doc firebase  realtime-database:  remove method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#delete_data)